# Shopware 6 cannot save theme configurations

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When I'm trying to change some variables e.g. the primary color in my theme configurations I get the following message:

> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500

The symfony profiler says the following:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: "Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" at /home/user/projects/project/vendor/sabberworm/php-css-parser/src/OutputFormatter.php line 27

```
[▼
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError {#63389 ▼
    -error: [▼
      "type" => 1
      "message" => "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"
      "file" => "/home/user/projects/project/vendor/sabberworm/php-css-parser/src/OutputFormatter.php"
      "line" => 27
    ]
    #message: "Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/user/projects/project/vendor/sabberworm/php-css-parser/src/OutputFormatter.php"
    #line: 27
  }
]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to increase the max execution time in the php.ini? - if this does not help, you might have a endless loop somewhere, which might be possible to find with Xdebug enabled

Comment: increasing max execution time fixed it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to say that it is solved. Either accept an answer that helped or, if no-one has posted the answer to your question but you have solved it yourself, write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As already said you have to increase the `max_execution_time`.

go on the server to `/etc`.
search by typing `find -name php.ini`.
*May differ between different distributions*
Choose the `php.ini` of the webserver. Thats not in `../cli/..` path!

1. Make a backup `sudo cp php.ini php.ini.bak`
2. Edit the file with nano `sudo nano php.ini`
3. Search: press: `ctrl` + `w`, enter `max_execution_time`, increase the number
4. Save: press: `ctrl` + `o`
5. Exit: press: `ctrl` + `x`
6. Restart your webserver. For apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2` or `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

The max execution time (`max_execution_time` in your `php.ini` used for webserver requests) needs to be increased.

Shopware is building the theme when saving the configuration, and this can take some time.